# cURL Load page SERVICE Unavailable

Tags: php, curl, remote-access

I was trying to load shareflare.net with cURL but i get Service Unavailable error every time.
From my localhost it load page normally, but from my web-host i get this error.... please help.

```
 $load=curl_init();

    curl_setopt($load, CURLOPT_URL, "http://shf.wm-panel.com/");
    curl_setopt($load, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($load, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    echo $result=curl_exec($load);
```

thanks!

Comment: When I try to load http://shf.wm-panel.com/ in my browser, I get a "Service Unavailable"  Seems like a server side error.

Comment: you're right, they dont allow access to IPs outside of Europe.
any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the site is returning a 503 error and the service really is unavailable from the US.

If you have a proxy you can use, then it isn't hard to tell cURL to use the proxy:

```
curl_setopt($load, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'some.hostname.com:8888');
```

I've never actually used the proxy tunnel, but I'm given to understand it works.  There are a few [proxy-related options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) you can use.

Comment: Service is online, when i use EU proxy... but my host server is in US... that is the problem.